# How can I automatically download lyrics in iTunes?

Tags: itunes, windows, lyrics

Is there a way to automatically download lyrics in iTunes?

Comment: In which operating system?

Comment: I am on Windows7

Comment: Is this on-topic for this site? Windows 7 is a Microsoft product.

Comment: iTunes is an Apple product.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality to download lyrics in iTunes, but there's a slew of software designed for this purpose:

Windows:

- [AutoLyrix](http://www.autolyrix.com/)
- [LyricsSeeker](http://www.metrolyrics.com/plugin.html)
- [MiniLyrics](http://www.crintsoft.com/minilyrics.htm)

OS X:

- [Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php)
- [LessLyrics](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/ipod_itunes/lesslyrics.html)

Comment: Actually, copy-pasting from the multitude of lyrics websites (AZLyrics, MetroLyrics, etc.) will be easier than downloading a whole another software.

Comment: All Windows links are no longer valid/supported

Answer (score 0):

For Windows: 
[LyricsXpert](http://LyricsXpert.com)

Works in all languages and free for now

Answer (score -1):

### To get lyrics on iTunes on your computer

- Right click the song you want lyrics for.
- Click "Get Info".
- Click "Lyrics".
- Find the lyrics to the song on a website such as azlyrics.com or metrolyrics.com
- Copy and paste the lyrics into the lyrics section.
- Click ok.

Now those lyrics are available from now on.

### To get lyrics on your iPhone or iPad

- Follow the above instructions to get the lyrics on your computer.
- Plug your device into your computer.
- Click sync under the device information.
- When the sync is finished, go to your music app, and play the song that you put lyrics in for.
- Tap the artwork, and lyrics should show up.

Comment: This is not automatic.