# Application to add lyrics to iTunes library

Tags: itunes, software-recommendation, lyrics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatically download lyrics](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10392/automatically-download-lyrics)

Is there an application that will go through your iTunes library and add the lyrics to the songs? If at all possible, it would be great if it was free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Lyrica 2](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/36373/lyrica-2) (1.99$), [Get Lyrical](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/25390/get-lyrical) and [GimmeSomeTune](http://gimmesometune.softonic.fr/mac).

Comment: @cksum Thanks to both of you! I will check these out.

Comment: Wow!! Get Lyrical is pretty awesome!