# Add Lyrics to iTunes with a program

Tags: itunes, macos, lyrics

I've been looking for a program ,or a widget, that could search for lyrics, download them and add them to iTunes (or display the lyrics while I'm playing a song).

All those I could find were outdated and didn't work correctly.

There are other program that can search for the lyrics but do not add them to iTunes, others that display lyrics already in iTunes but not both.

iTunes version : 12.3.0.44

OS X version : Yosemite (10.10.5)

Comment: I've tried the solutions in http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10392 . none of them works correctly. Alistair's answer helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [jwzlyrics](https://www.jwz.org/jwzlyrics/). It picks up songs changes in iTunes (and Spotify), finds lyrics and displays them in a window.

It's dependent on https://lyrics.wikia.com/ for it's lyrics, and works quite well for me.

Answer (score 1):

[Get Lyrical](http://shullian.com/get_lyrical.php) is an alternative. As far as I know it doesn't work with Apple Music files.

Comment: I've tried Get Lyrical it's very buggy, thanks any way